Referencing Json files in Storyline 360
Storyline gives advice on how to add external Javascript to a course:
https://access.articulate.com/support/article/Articulate-Storyline-360-JavaScript-Best-Practices-and-Examples
By adding the following to the story.html file:


<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2" SRC="/story_content/MyJavaScriptFunctions.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>



And then inserting the .js file into the \story_content folder.
Is there a way to insert a .json file into \story_content and have javascript reference it?
